# App can not access sdcard when eclipse+adt connect to real mobile device

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, adt

When eclipse+adt connect to an avd emulator, my app run well and it will read/write the sdcard in this avd emulator.

Now I connect eclipse+adt to a real device by USB. Eclipse+adt transfre app to the real device and app run successful. But, when app access sdcard, it failed. When I disconnect USB, app can access sdcard. Of course, I can't get the log out.

What shall I do? I want debug app on real device and it read/write sdcard and I want the log out.

Addition, when I connect USB, device system give a hint: can't visit sdcard memory.

Comment: are you trying to access your memory card from ddms?

Comment: I have not try this for this is not I want. I can access real device sdcard in "file explore" of eclipse. I mean, eclipse can access real device sdcard, while app running on the real device can not access this sdcard.

Comment: what do u mean by "eclipse can access"... are you reffering to the emulator?

Comment: Hi, I mean, when I debug app by emulator, eclipse transfer app to emulator, and in the "file explore" window of eclipse I can see the sdcard or other memory of the emulator. When I debug app at real device, the "file explore" window of eclipse can also show the memory or sdcard of the real device, but my app can not access the sdcard of the real device. Can you know what I mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I find the way. When USB connect to PC, I should set the connection as "only battery charge", then both eclipse and app on this mobile can visit SD card. The total setting about USB connection type include: 1, ask when connection, 2, only battery charge, 3, open memory card. I choose the second. I try this in my mobile phone of "xiaomi" which is famous brand of a China company.

Answer (score 1):

To access the sd card of a phone, we need to root the phone. Once you root a device, you can even see the database of the aplication that you are developing.

Comment: hi, finally I find the way. When USB connect to PC, I should set the connection as "only battery charge", then both eclipse and app in this mobile can visit SD card.